# BASH Script - Find Replace multiple values

Tags: bash, replace, find

I've got a very simple bash script which I'm passing values to

I want to strip the prefix from the value passed to the script.

The works and strips `test-` from the passed value..

```
IN=$1
arrIN=(${IN//test-/})
echo $arrIN
```

So test-12345 returns 12345

Is there anyway to amend this so it will remove either `test-` or `local-` ?

I've tried :

```
arrIN=(${IN//test-|local-/})
```

But that didn't work..

Thanks

Comment: `${var##*-}` gets the portion from last `-` to the end of the string. But you are using array notation, so it is not clear if this is enough/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sed as below:

```
IN=$1
arrIN=$(echo $IN | sed -r 's/test-|local-//g')
echo $arrIN
```

Here sed will search for "test-" or "local-" and remove them completely anywhere in the whole input.

Comment: Thanks - I've gone for this answer as I understand it easier..
When I look back at this in 6 months, I'll know what it does :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change "test-" or "local-" to "", you could use a command like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/test-|local-/, ""); print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`   and get the exact result

```
IN=$1
arrIN=$( echo $IN | sed 's/[^-]\+.//')
echo $arrIN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `extglob` activated:

```
shopt -s extglob
arrIN=(${IN//+(test-|local-)/})
```

---

From [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
  ?(pattern-list)  
         Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns  
  *(pattern-list)  
         Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns  
  +(pattern-list)  
         Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns  
  @(pattern-list)  
         Matches one of the given patterns  
  !(pattern-list)  
         Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```